# React to rxjs unsubscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to wrap an event-based API with RXJS Observables, but I can't figure out how to clean up after myself after an unsubscription happens.

This is pretty much how I would sync up the subscription with the Observable and the event-based API:

```
interface SomeEventService{
    registerListener(messageName: string, messageContent: Something): Listener;
    unregisterListener(listener: Listener);
}

class MyWrapper {
    private eventService: SomeEventService;

    streamOfSomething$(): Observable<Something> {
        return Observable.create((observer: Observer<Something>) => {
            // Create a listener, and relay events to the Observable
            const listener = this.eventService.registerListener("something", something => {
                observer.next(something);
            })
            // Now what?
        })
    }
}
```

The problem here is that at some time in the future I want to call `eventService.unregisterListener`, e.g when the consumer of `streamOfSomething$` unsubscribes from the stream.

**The question:** How do I do this? As far as I can tell there is no event or callback I can use on my `observer` to run code after an unsubscribe happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyWrapper {
    private eventService: SomeEventService;

    streamOfSomething$(): Observable<Something> {
        return Observable.create((observer: Observer<Something>) => {
            // Create a listener, and relay events to the Observable
            const listener = this.eventService.registerListener("something", something => {
                observer.next(something);
            })
            // Now what?
             return () => { this.eventService.unRegisterListener(); };
        })
    }
}
```

the function which you will return will be called when user call the unsubscribe()

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much!